# Spring: SimpleJdbcCall with dynamic parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have a dao that uses [SimpleJdbcCall](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html) to call postgres functions:

```
public final class AuthDAO extends UntypedActor {

    private final ActorRef manager;

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private final SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

    public AuthDAO(ActorRef manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
        jdbcTemplate = DBConfig.jdbcTemplate();
        jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withSchemaName("auth")
                .withCatalogName("public")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
    }

    public static Props create(ActorRef manager) {
        return Props.create(AuthDAO.class, manager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object o) throws Throwable {
        if (o instanceof DBMessage) {

            DBMessage message = (DBMessage) o;
            jdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("login", Types.VARCHAR));
            Map<String, Object> response = jdbcCall
                    .withProcedureName(message.getProcedure())
                    .execute(message.getParams());

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But now I have to explicitly declare in parameters of a function by calling `jdbcCall.declareParameters()` otherwise code won't work.

So is there a way to dynamically detect name and type of function parameters and use such dao to call different functions passing only a function name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [figured it out](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-2).

> Explicit declarations are necessary if the database you use is not a
>   Spring-supported database. Currently Spring supports metadata lookup
>   of stored procedure calls for the following databases: **Apache Derby,
>   DB2, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, and Sybase**. We also support
>   metadata lookup of stored functions for **MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server,
>   and Oracle**.

And, omg, I use Postgres.